# Como desserializar um polígono geométrico com Gson?

Tags: java, json, vraptor, gson, desserialização

Estou usando Vraptor 4 e a intenção é criar uma classe converter de polygon que faça a desserialização e que serialize. Meu problema está apenas em desserializar. Como desserializar um polígono geométrico com Gson?

Segue o json no qual preciso desserializar

```
{
   "perimeter": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        -60.908203125,
                        -18.6328125
                    ],
                    [
                        -54.140625,
                        -14.677734375
                    ],
                    [
                        -51.6796875,
                        -23.291015625
                    ],
                    [
                        -58.88671875,
                        -22.1484375
                    ],
                    [
                        -60.908203125,
                        -18.6328125
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: não seria Json ?

Comment: @Otto Não: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: @tmvolpato se possível, edite a pergunta com o problema que está tendo na deserialização.

Comment: Pode deixar irei fazer isso, obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro definimos seu pojo

```
public class  Perimeter {
  String type;
  List<List<Float>> coordinates;
  /*
  ...
  constructor
  ...
  getters setters
  */
}
```

O [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) tem o método [fromJson](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) que faz a leitura de um Json (string, buffer, jsonnode) para o objeto desejado.

```
Perimeter perimeter = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Perimeter.class);
```