# Manipular um JSON com a biblioteca GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Este é o json:

```
{
"professor": [
{
  "latitude": -23.1843473,
  "longitude": -45.8840718,
  "title": "Microcamp",
  "endereco": "rua vilaça 2010"
},
{
  "latitude": -23.1843473,
  "longitude": -45.8840718,
  "title": "Microcamp",
  "endereco": "rua vilaça 2010"
}
],
"medico": [
{
  "latitude": -23.1843473,
  "longitude": -45.8840718,
  "title": "Microcamp",
  "endereco": "rua vilaça 2010"
},
{
  "latitude": -23.1843473,
  "longitude": -45.8840718,
  "title": "Microcamp",
  "endereco": "rua vilaça 2010"
}
]
}
```

Gostaria de manipulá-lo, que seria ler o `json`, e gravar mais dados.

Por exemplo uma nova profissão e um novo local, podendo cadastrar vários locais em uma profissão. Ou seja gostaria de transformar esse `json` em objeto com `gson`!

Comment: Você possui uma classe `Profissoes`, ou várias como: `Professor`, `Medico`, etc? Veja se [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37249/como-desserializar-um-pol%C3%ADgono-geom%C3%A9trico-com-gson?rq=1) resposta te ajuda.

Comment: Nao possuo essas classes, iria ser dinâmico!

Comment: existe a possibilidade de ser criado?

Comment: eu tinha visto essa que voce mandou eu dar uma olhada, vou tentar fazer um exemplo para ver

Comment: Você tem que criar a classe necessária para desserializar seu JSON, vou tentar te explicar em uma resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Zulian, estou no aguardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você possui profissões e locais em seu JSON, precisa ter essas classes com esses mesmos atributos para poder transformar esse JSON em um objeto manipulável.

A estrutura básica nesse seu caso é: um **array de Profissões** que possui um **array de Locais**. Este JSON aí precisa de mudanças, pois possui um array de `Locais` mas não um de profissões, pois falta uma chave ( [ ) no começo e no final de tudo. Além disso você precisa inserir um atributo para a descrição da profissão. Primeiro você precisa tratar isso para não ter uma classe de cada profissão. Ex correto:

```
[
  {
    "descricao": "Professor",
    "local": [
      {
        "latitude": -23.1843473,
        "longitude": -45.8840718,
        "title": "Microcamp",
        "endereco": "rua vilaça 2010"
      },
      {
        "latitude": -23.1843473,
        "longitude": -45.8840718,
        "title": "Microcamp",
        "endereco": "rua vilaça 2010"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "descricao": "Médico",
    "local": [
      {
        "latitude": -23.1843473,
        "longitude": -45.8840718,
        "title": "Microcamp",
        "endereco": "rua vilaça 2010"
      },
      {
        "latitude": -23.1843473,
        "longitude": -45.8840718,
        "title": "Microcamp",
        "endereco": "rua vilaça 2010"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Depois é só criar as classes:

Profissao:

```
public class Profissao {
  String descricao;
  ArrayList<Local> local;

  public Profissao() {  //construtor
    this.descricao = "";
    this.local = new ArrayList();
  }
  // setters e getters aqui
}
```

Local:

```
public class Local {
  Double latitute;
  Double longitude;
  String title;
  String endereco;

  public Local() {  //construtor
    this.latitute = 0.00;
    this.longitude = 0.00;
    this.title = "";
    this.endereco = "";
  }
  // setters e getters aqui
}
```

Depois de ter essas classes, para desserializar seu JSON é fácil, utilize o método `gson.fromJson` passando seu `json` e a classe a ser utilizada. Ex:

```
Profissao[] profissoes = gson.fromJson(json, Profissao[].class);
```

Se seu JSON estiver correto, você terá um array de profissoes com seus respectivos locais.

Note que o nome dos atributos devem ser iguais aos do JSON para o Gson pegar automaticamente, caso queira utilizar outros nomes, utilize anotações próprias do Gson.

PS.: Há [um site bem bacana](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) que gera as classes baseado em seu JSON!

---

### Utilizando `List`

Para trabalhar com arrays dinâmicos, como `List` por exemplo, você precisa utilizar o [`TypeToken`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) do Gson para converter seu json em um `List`. Depois fica fácil adicionar mais objetos e transformar para json novamente. Ex.:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Profissao>>(){}.getType();
List<Profissao> profissoes = gson.fromJson(json, type); //converte o json para uma lista

Profissao profissaoNova = new Profissao(); //cria uma nova profissao
profissaoNova.setDescricao("Programador");

profissoes.add(profissaoNova); //adiciona a profissao no array

String jsonString = gson.toJson(profissoes); //transforma para json novamente
```

Comment: O codigo esta super funcional estou conseguindo ler perfeitamente! e seu eu quiser cadastrar mais dados dentro desse json como consigo fazer? voce poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você precisa utilizar listas para facilitar. Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: beleza, quando coloquei o codigo ele disse para eu importar o type, porem apareceu varias opções de type tem alguma que seria a correta?

Comment: Consegui aqui, outra e ultima duvida se eu for cadastrar um local eu faria de que forma ? <3 valeu nois

Comment: Crie um local assim: `Local local = new Local();`. Sete os atributos necessários. Ex.: `local.setTitle("Teste");`. Depois adicione no array de locais da profissão, fazendo algo do tipo: `profissaoNova.getLocal().add(local);`.

Comment: Cara você é um DEUS! muito obrigado salvou minha pele na faculdade ! <3