# Retorno de Web Service é uma string, como posso consultar os dados?

Tags: java, json

Estou consumindo um Web Service , segue o código do JAVA (JSP):

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%-- start web service invocation --%><hr/>
<%
try {
com.totvs.framework.ws.execbo.service.WebServiceExecBO service = new com.totvs.framework.ws.execbo.service.WebServiceExecBO();
com.totvs.framework.ws.execbo.service.ExecBOServiceEndpoint port = service.getWebServiceExecBOPort();
 // TODO initialize WS operation arguments here

String user       = request.getParameter("centroCusto");
String token      = port.userLogin(user);
String path       = "dzp/teste001.p";
String procedure  = "ws-busca-ccusto";
String json       = "[{\"name\":\"tt-ccusto\",\"type\":\"output\",\"dataType\":\"temptable\",\"value\":{\"name\":\"tt-ccusto\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"cod-ccusto\", \"label\":\"codccusto\",\"type\":\"character\"},{\"name\":\"descricao\",  \"label\":\"descricao\",\"type\":\"character\"}],\"records\":[]}}]";

// TODO process result here
java.lang.String result = port.callProcedureWithToken(token, path, procedure, json);
out.println("Result = "+result);
} catch (Exception ex) {
// TODO handle custom exceptions here
    out.println("ERROR = "+ex);
}
%>
<%-- end web service invocation --%><hr/>
```

Que retorna uma listagem de centros de custo:

```
Result = [{"dataType":"temptable","name":"tt-ccusto","value":"{\"records\":[{\"descricao\":\"Exclusivo Cadastro de Itens\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"00000001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Administracao\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10011001\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Administracao\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10011999\"},{\"descricao\":\"Tecnologia da Informacao\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10111001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Recursos Humanos\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10211001\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Seguranca do Trabalho\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10211002\"},{\"descricao\":\"Ambulatorio\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10211003\"},{\"descricao\":\"Afastados\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10211004\"},{\"descricao\":\"Aprendiz \\\/ Senai\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10211005\"},{\"descricao\":\"Controladoria\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10311001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Financeiro\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10311002\"},{\"descricao\":\"Fiscal\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10311003\"},{\"descricao\":\"Logistica\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10411001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Compras\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10411002\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Almoxarifado Geral\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10411998\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Expedicao\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10411999\"},{\"descricao\":\"Vendas\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10511001\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Vendas\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10511998\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Vendas\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10511999\"},{\"descricao\":\"Juridico\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10611001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Administracao da Producao\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23121001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Planejamento e Controle da Producao-Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23121002\"},{\"descricao\":\"Expedicao\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23121003\"},{\"descricao\":\"Almoxarifado\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23121004\"},{\"descricao\":\"Seguranca do Trabalho\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23121005\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Producao Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23121998\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Producao Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23121999\"},{\"descricao\":\"Manutencao Fabril - Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23221001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Manutencao Patrimonial - Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23221002\"},{\"descricao\":\"Manutencao Automacao - Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23221003\"},{\"descricao\":\"Ferramentaria - Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23321001\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Matrizaria Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23321999\"},{\"descricao\":\"Ferramentaria - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23322001\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Afiacao - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23322002\"},{\"descricao\":\"Gestao da Qualidade - Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23421001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Engenharia de Pesquisa e Desenvol - Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23521001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Engenharia de Produto - Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23521002\"},{\"descricao\":\"Engenharia de Processos - Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23521003\"},{\"descricao\":\"Laboratorio Metalurgico - Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23521004\"},{\"descricao\":\"Laboratorio Testes Mecanicos\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23521005\"},{\"descricao\":\"Desenvolvimento de Novos Produtos\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23521006\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Engenharia Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23521999\"},{\"descricao\":\"Corte - Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25121001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Corte - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25132001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Forjarias - Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25221001\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Forjaria II Custos Fixos\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25221996\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Forjaria II Custos Fixos\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25221997\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Forjaria II\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25221998\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Forjaria I\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25221999\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Forjaria II Grupo 21 - Variav\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25232001\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Forjaria II Grupo 22 - Variav\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25232002\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Forjaria II Grupo 31 - Variav\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25232003\"},{\"descricao\":\"Forjaria II Grupo 34 - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25232004\"},{\"descricao\":\"Forjaria II Grupo 35 - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25232005\"},{\"descricao\":\"Forjaria II Grupo 38 - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25232006\"},{\"descricao\":\"Forjaria II Grupo 41 - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25232007\"},{\"descricao\":\"Forjaria II Grupo 51 - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25232008\"},{\"descricao\":\"Forjaria II Grupo 32 - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25232009\"},{\"descricao\":\"Grupo de Forjamento 42\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25232010\"},{\"descricao\":\"Grupo de Forjamento 33\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25232011\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Forjaria II Grupo 32 - Variav\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25232997\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Forjaria II Grupo 33 - Variav\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25232998\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Forjaria I Grupo 2 Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25232999\"},{\"descricao\":\"Tratamento Termico - Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25321001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Tratamento Termico - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25332001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Acabamento - Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25421001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Acabamento - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25432001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Pintura - Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25521001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Pintura - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25532001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Mini Fabrica - Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25621001\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Usinagem Terceiro Ponto - Var\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25632001\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Usin.Braco-Eixos e Mangas Eix\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25632002\"},{\"descricao\":\"Usinagem de Esferas Agricolas - Var\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25632003\"},{\"descricao\":\"Montagem de Conjuntos Tubulares - Variav\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25632004\"},{\"descricao\":\"Montagem de Conjuntos Barras - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25632005\"},{\"descricao\":\"Usinagem Flange do Freio - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25632006\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Conj.Manga Eixo Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25632998\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Conj.Eixo Dianteiro\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25632999\"},{\"descricao\":\"Usinagem - Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25721001\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Usinagem Custo Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25721999\"},{\"descricao\":\"Usinagem Eixos - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25732001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Usinagem Flanges e Yokes - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25732002\"},{\"descricao\":\"Usinagem Eixo Longo - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25732003\"},{\"descricao\":\"Usinagem Ponta de Eixo - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25732004\"},{\"descricao\":\"Usinagem Bracos - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25732005\"},{\"descricao\":\"Usinagem Aneis - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25732006\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Usinagem Brochadeiras - Varia\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25732007\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Usinagem Virabrequins - Varia\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25732008\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Inducao - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25732009\"},{\"descricao\":\"Usinagem Trunnion - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25732010\"},{\"descricao\":\"Usinagem Diversos - Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25732011\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.)\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25732995\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.)\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25732996\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Usinagem Pesada Variavel\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25732997\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Usin.Geradora de Engrenagem\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25732998\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Usinagem Eletroferragem\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"25732999\"},{\"descricao\":\"Rateio Lotacao\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"92000001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Rateio Horas de Producao\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"92000002\"},{\"descricao\":\"Rateio Energia Eletrica\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"92000003\"},{\"descricao\":\"Rateio Area Construida\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"92000004\"},{\"descricao\":\"Rateio Area Predio I\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"92000005\"},{\"descricao\":\"Rateio Predio H\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"92000006\"},{\"descricao\":\"Rateio Predio G\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"92000007\"},{\"descricao\":\"Rateio Predio F\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"92000008\"},{\"descricao\":\"Rateio Predio B\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"92000009\"},{\"descricao\":\"Rateio Gas Natural\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"92000010\"},{\"descricao\":\"Rateio Predio J\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"92000011\"},{\"descricao\":\"Rateio Predio 2\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"92000012\"},{\"descricao\":\"Rateio Lotacao por m²\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"92000013\"},{\"descricao\":\"Rateio Rampa da Lavagem\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"92000014\"},{\"descricao\":\"Rateio Vazao ETE\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"92000015\"},{\"descricao\":\"Execucao Orcamentaria\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"93000001\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Orcamentos\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"99999999\"},{\"descricao\":\"TESTE\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10011999\"},{\"descricao\":\"ORCAMENTOS\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"99999999\"}],\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"cod-ccusto\",\"label\":\"codccusto\",\"type\":\"character\"},{\"name\":\"descricao\",\"label\":\"descricao\",\"type\":\"character\"}]}","type":"output"}]
```

Agora, eu gostaria de tratar esse dados, por exemplo: mostrando todas as descrições de todos os centros de custo.
Pensei em transformar essa String em um objeto ou em um JSON para percorrer de alguma forma todos os itens, porem não tenho certeza do que estou fazendo ou como deveria fazer.

A minha pergunta é:
Qual a forma mais prática de transformar essa String em algo que eu posso consultar?

***Segundo a orientação do user Renan, adaptei o código dele e funcionou***:

```
JSON.JSONObject object    = new JSON.JSONArray(result).getJSONObject(0);
JSON.JSONObject object2   = new JSON.JSONObject(object.getString("value"));
JSON.JSONArray arrayFinal = object2.getJSONArray("records");

for(int i = 0; i < arrayFinal.length(); i++){
    final String descricao = arrayFinal.getJSONObject(i).getString("descricao"), ccusto = arrayFinal.getJSONObject(i).getString("cod-ccusto");
    out.println(descricao + " - " + ccusto + "</br>");
}
```

Irei deixar a resposta dele como a correta pois ela abrange mais a questão.

Comment: Você poderia criar uma classe `CentrosDeCusto` com os atributos `codigo` e `descricao` e depois utilizar a biblioteca GSON para transformar este JSON em objetos dessa classe. Veja se [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250819/manipular-um-json-com-a-biblioteca-gson/250860#250860) te ajuda!

Comment: Sobre o Gson, eu não encontrei o package com as classes para colocar no netbeans.

Comment: As libs podem ser encontradas [aqui](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.6.2/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você tem um objeto `Record` com os atributos `descricao` e `codCusto`, pode utilizar o [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) ou o [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) que permitem mapear as chaves do JSON aos atributos da classe. [Nessa pergunta <sup>(en)</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2378402/4056678) existem algumas diferenças entre elas.

Se precisa de um tratamento simples, por exemplo, somente obter o array `records` e iterar pelos itens, pode utilizar a [JSON (org.json)](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) - existem outras implementações em Java no [org.json](http://www.json.org/), pode consultar.

```
final String response = "[{\"dataType\":\"temptable\",\"name\":\"tt-ccusto\",\"value\":{\"records\":[{\"descricao\":\"Exclusivo Cadastro de Itens\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"00000001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Administracao\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10011001\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Administracao\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10011999\"},{\"descricao\":\"Tecnologia da Informacao\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10111001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Recursos Humanos\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10211001\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Seguranca do Trabalho\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10211002\"},{\"descricao\":\"Ambulatorio\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10211003\"},{\"descricao\":\"Afastados\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10211004\"},{\"descricao\":\"Aprendiz \\\\\\/ Senai\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10211005\"},{\"descricao\":\"Controladoria\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10311001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Financeiro\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10311002\"},{\"descricao\":\"Fiscal\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10311003\"},{\"descricao\":\"Logistica\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10411001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Compras\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10411002\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Almoxarifado Geral\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10411998\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Expedicao\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10411999\"},{\"descricao\":\"Vendas\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10511001\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Vendas\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10511998\"},{\"descricao\":\"(Desat.) - Vendas\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10511999\"},{\"descricao\":\"Juridico\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"10611001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Administracao da Producao\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23121001\"},{\"descricao\":\"Planejamento e Controle da Producao-Fixo\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23121002\"},{\"descricao\":\"Expedicao\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23121003\"},{\"descricao\":\"Almoxarifado\",\"cod-ccusto\":\"23121004\"}]}}]";

JSONObject object = new JSONArray(response).getJSONObject(0);

object.getJSONObject("value").getJSONArray("records").forEach(item -> {
   JSONObject record = (JSONObject) item;

   final String descricao = record.getString("descricao"),
                ccusto = record.getString("cod-ccusto");

   System.out.println("Descrição: " + descricao + " - Código: " + ccusto);
});
```

No seu exemplo, o array `Result` contém somente um elemento, então peguei o primeiro (e nesse caso único) pelo índice. Tendo o objeto JSON, basta a chave `value` e dentro dela iterar sobre os elementos (também `JSONObject`) de `records`. O resultado será este:

```
Descrição: Exclusivo Cadastro de Itens - Código: 00000001
Descrição: Administracao - Código: 10011001
Descrição: (Desat.) - Administracao - Código: 10011999
Descrição: Tecnologia da Informacao - Código: 10111001
Descrição: Recursos Humanos - Código: 10211001
Descrição: (Desat.) - Seguranca do Trabalho - Código: 10211002
Descrição: Ambulatorio - Código: 10211003
Descrição: Afastados - Código: 10211004
Descrição: Aprendiz \/ Senai - Código: 10211005
Descrição: Controladoria - Código: 10311001
Descrição: Financeiro - Código: 10311002
Descrição: Fiscal - Código: 10311003
Descrição: Logistica - Código: 10411001
Descrição: Compras - Código: 10411002
Descrição: (Desat.) - Almoxarifado Geral - Código: 10411998
Descrição: (Desat.) - Expedicao - Código: 10411999
Descrição: Vendas - Código: 10511001
Descrição: (Desat.) - Vendas - Código: 10511998
Descrição: (Desat.) - Vendas - Código: 10511999
Descrição: Juridico - Código: 10611001
Descrição: Administracao da Producao - Código: 23121001
Descrição: Planejamento e Controle da Producao-Fixo - Código: 23121002
Descrição: Expedicao - Código: 23121003
Descrição: Almoxarifado - Código: 23121004
```

Comment: Acabei editando a pergunta melhorando o JSON que me retorna, ele tem algumas características que no tratamento simples estou com dificuldade para resolver. Sobre o Gson ou jackson, eu não encontrei o package com as classes para colocar no netbeans.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o que eu fiz e o que dá erro (500 not found)

Comment: Haha o problema estava no forEach. Fiz com for e foi de boa! Valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: Eu linkei o GitHub de ambos o projetos, se estiver utilizando o Maven é mais fácil ainda incluir as dependências. Sobre `forEach`, utilizei essa forma pois respondi me baseando no Java 8. Se estiver utilizando Java <=7 é preciso iterar utilizando loops mesmo **=)**